# Getting the index of an array item in vanilla javascript when new items are pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 <label for="accTopic">Accordion Topic</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="accTopic" id="accTopic"><br/><br/>

            <label for="accordionPanel">Accordion Content</label><br/>
            <textarea name="accordionPanel" id="accordionPanel" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br>

let items = [];

function getItems() {
        let accTopic = document.getElementById("accTopic").value;
        let accPanel = CKEDITOR.instances.accordionPanel.getData();
        items.push(
            {
                topic: accTopic,
                panel: accPanel,
            }
        );
   return(items);
}
```

Hello and thank you for looking at this. I am hoping to figure out how to get the index of the above array so I can assign to a button for editing.

Project Info:
I'm hoping to create a tool that customers can use to build an accordion without writing HTML but just pasting the HTML into the source code of CK Editor.

My obstacle is assigning the index of the array to a variable that I can reference from the HTML to edit the topic/detail of an accordion item.

Basically, if I had to talk it out, would go like this:

- Accordion item created. It's the third item in the array
- There is a for loop that assigns the appropriate classes, IDs and attributes to the items which allows expanding/collapsing of items
- There is an 'Edit' button that allows someone to edit the accordion item, which is identified by the index of the array via an HTML attribute. This assignment would be assigned in the for... loop. If it's the third item, the index would be 2 which would trigger an edit function.

Am I off-base with this? Please let me know and thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get all the items using `document.querySelectorAll` and get the index of the clicked element using `Array#indexOf`.

```js
let items = [...document.querySelector('.accordion').querySelectorAll('.accordion-item')];
let index = items.indexOf(elem);
```

Comment: Hello - would this work on event listener that is assigned to the parent element of the accordion? IE.. And thank you, by the way. I appreciate your time on this.

Comment: @blur It would be easier to help if you provide all the relevant code.